# Elasticsearch: strategy to process large historic data in a live cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `3 Node` Elasticsearch Cluster `7.16`.

I have a single index, with `3 primary shards`, replication = 1.

This cluster is live in a sense that it is continously indexing data. Also, queries are being made against the cluster multiple times every day.

Now, I have a need to index a huge amount of historic data(*about 3 years of data*) into the cluster, without affecting the AS-IS indexing, query happening every day.

So, I am thinking about preparing a strategy to tune the cluster in such a way that this historic migration happens smoothly, without affecting live performance.

One way, I am thinking is to `add a data Node` during the period of this historic migration and turn off later. Would that be a good approach ? Would that instead hinder performance due to rebalancing needed ? Should I be looking for a different type of [Node Role](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#node-roles)?

Should I consider other strategies like increasing the shard size ?
Any advices and suggestions on this problem would be helpful.

Comment: can you provide more info like the data size which you are planning to bring in after this 3 years data addition?
also the current data size of each primary shard?

Comment: also is there a constraint on the cluster size in terms of number of nodes? I am saying this cuz you have mentioned that you'll scale down the cluster once the indexing is done. Another thing is that are you adding the data in the same index or creating a new index for this historical data?

Comment: @ArnavSinghChauhan `1).` The 3 years of data resides in a different data source(non-Elastic), which needs to be in Elasticsearch. It's about 100 GB of data. The current data size of primary shard is 200 GB per shard. `2).` There is actually no constraint in terms of number of nodes in a cluster. I only mentioned "add 1 node and remove later" approach as one possible way to tackle this data loading. I want to make sure the performance of current index is not badly impacted by this loading period.`3).` I need to add this data in the same index, which is actively functional and daily used.

Comment: As a practice, shard size should be between 10-50 GB, anything above that will increase load on nodes with large shards, making the cluster less efficient.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html
To recreate a new index with proper shard sizes, you can use the reindex API, it comes in handy for such use cases.
Now once you are sure that the current index is properly sharded, the queries on it will be more efficient and overall cluster load will remain balanced and well distributed

Comment: now tif you are sure that the data is around 100 GB, based on your current heap consumption of the cluster, take a call on how much new data nodes addition which will cater to this historical index 
start with a 5 primary -1 replica configs, and go through this doc
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/tune-for-indexing-speed.html
best is to make refresh interval as 30s for both indexes unless explicitly required by your application. You can also index without replicas and later change no of replica setting. All this can be done through kibana as well

Comment: That link you shared is indeed very useful and informative :)